# Must Crypt A Session?

Tags: php, session, crypt

I use the sessions for login system:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
```

I only save id on session and i use `session_regenerate_id()` on top of all page, this method is secure?
And i use `session_regenerate_id()` on top of all page, but the people can change the session and set any id?

Comment: People can set a different id, but they have no way of knowing what id will be avlid.

Comment: What you're doing won't actually change anything, an attacker would be able to see what session_id the information was coming in, and coming out, unless you use https what you're doing doesn't change anything. use https, and regenerate the ID after login to protect against MITM attacks.

Comment: i use  `session_rigenerate_id()` for change the ID of the session

Comment: @serakfalcon if you placed yourself in the position someone can successfully execute a MITM attack, session_ids are the last of your issues, because he can get the username and password aswell as any other data you send over

Comment: @LucaB. That's my point, I think the OP is overly concerned about something that doesn't even matter if proper safeguards aren't in place.

Comment: @serakfalcon I got your comment wrong then :)

Comment: With MITM attack, you are talking about session hijacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. A client can't read SESSIONS (at least in PHP), the only thing a client has access to is an ID generated by the server that is then used to retrieve session values **server-side**

Comment: but the session_id is a cookie, so the people can change it?

Comment: session_id is a cookie but is a quite long hash, so trying to bruteforce it will likely end up with nothing since session_id changes when the session is collected